# Problem in python opening a csv file when script is executed with PHP

Tags: python, php, csv

I have two files, test.php and test.py. So test.php runs the script test.py, which opens a csv file and adds a row. It works fine on local host, and test.py works fine on the server from command line. However, when test.py is called by test.php on the server, it does run the program but it fails to open the csv, and then the program fails.

Any help, including how to further troubleshoot it, would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**test.php**

```
<?php
$output = exec("python test.py");
echo $output;
?>
```

**test.py**

```
import csv

fp = open('myfile.csv', 'w') #program fails at this line on server
myFile = csv.writer(fp)
myFile.writerow(["blue", "orange", "yellow"])
fp.close()
```

Comment: I'd guess privilege or access right issue? Your [mcve] seems to be incomplete (missing full traceback)…

Comment: Afraid that's all the code I have. What is full traceback and how can I get that for you? As test.py works on command line, and the whole thing works on localhost, I'm struggling to get any error messages.

Any idea how I could figure out which privilege or access rights issue I'm having? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if you got this question answered, but I tried this code on a local server and I didn't have an issue on my side. As far as the full traceback part, when you ran this code and saw that the program failed at the `fp = open(...)` line, how did you know the program failed at that particular line? Was there a place where you saw the error message displayed and the line number of where the error happened? If so, that type of message might be related to the traceback information. For your other question, have you had the chance to try this code in your local home directory?